# Multiple directories with multiple files in U-SQL without date time

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

i want to read multiple files from multiple folder using U-SQL without date time.
folder structure is

input
     input1
           file1.csv
           file2.csv
     input2
          file3.csv

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
@"input/input{*}/file{*}.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Jamil's answer will work.  If you want more control, you can simply list the files you want as a comma separated list, eg

```
@data =
    EXTRACT col1 int,
            col2 int,
            col3 int,
            col4 int
    FROM "input/input1/file1.csv",
         "input/input1/file2.csv",
         "input/input2/file3.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv();
```